# How to Read in Data

Tags: read.table

I understand questions like this have been asked before ... and I have read all the comments, but I can still not figure out why R is refusing to read my data and giving me the error: "Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 2 elements"

The data copied directly from my RTF file is:

```
R      EI    SN    TF    JP    Drink     Count
1      E     S     T     J     Often     10
2      E     S     T     P     Often     8
3      E     S     F     J     Often     5
4      E     S     F     P     Often     7
5      E     S     T     J     Rarely    67
6      E     S     T     P     Rarely    34
7      E     S     F     J     Rarely    101
8      E     S     F     P     Rarely    72
9      E     N     T     J     Often     3
10     E     N     T     P     Often     2
11     E     N     F     J     Often     4
12     E     N     F     P     Often     15
13     E     N     T     J     Rarely    20
14     E     N     T     P     Rarely    16
15     E     N     F     J     Rarely    27
16     E     N     F     P     Rarely    65
17     I     S     T     J     Often     17
18     I     S     T     P     Often     3
19     I     S     F     J     Often     6
20     I     S     F     P     Often     4
21     I     S     T     J     Rarely    123
22     I     S     T     P     Rarely    49
23     I     S     F     J     Rarely    132
24     I     S     F     P     Rarely    102
25     I     N     T     J     Often     1
26     I     N     T     P     Often     5
27     I     N     F     J     Often     1
28     I     N     F     P     Often     6
29     I     N     T     J     Rarely    12
30     I     N     T     P     Rarely    30
31     I     N     F     J     Rarely    30
32     I     N     F     P     Rarely    73
```

NO MATTER what file format I use, it refuses to read in the data... Thank you for any suggestions !

Comment: What's your R code? Why do you want to read RTF? Usually one tries to read plain text files.

Comment: read.table("/Users/king-of-cards/Desktop/drink.rtf",header=T). It doesn't matter if its rtf, or txt, or .dat, R wont read it on my computer.

Comment: I used rtf because thats the default for text edit on my mac, but txt doesn't accomplish anything either.

Comment: You should not add code as a comment, please edit your question. Create a minimal example that compiles/runs and includes your problem. Otherwise we need to guess. I doubt that the editor writes RTF, as this is formatted text.